# Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function. Error even after not using the slim version

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, ajax

I'm trying to make a dynamic dropdown menu and I'm getting this error in console.

```
Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function
at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous> ((index):148)
at HTMLSelectElement.dispatch (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
at HTMLSelectElement.v.handle (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
```

I'm following a page to make this dropdown and this is the [link](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html).

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from . import forms 

from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login,logout
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect
from django.forms import modelformset_factory
import requests
import urllib.parse
from apply_main.models import *

def apply(request):

    def getLonLat(subdistrict,district,state):
        address = str(subdistrict)+", "+str(district)+", "+str(state)
        url = 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search/' + urllib.parse.quote(address) +'?format=json'

        response = requests.get(url).json()
        return response[0]["lat"],response[0]["lon"]

    form = forms.ApplyForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.ApplyForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            application = form.save(commit=False)

            
            application.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('apply_main:apply'))
    
    context = {
        'form':form,
    }
    return render(request, 'apply_main/apply_form.html', context)

def load_districts(request):
    state_id = request.GET.get('state')
    print(state_id,"\n"*5)
    districts = District.objects.filter(state_id=state_id).order_by('name')
    return render(request, 'apply_main/dist_dropdown_list_options.html', {'districts': districts})

def load_subdistricts(request):
    district_id = request.GET.get('district')
    subdistricts = Subdistrict.objects.filter(district_id=district_id).order_by('name')
    return render(request, 'apply_main/subdist_dropdown_list_options.html', {'subdistricts': subdistricts})
```

model.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class State(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
class District(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    state = models.ForeignKey(State,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Subdistrict(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    district = models.ForeignKey(District,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Apply(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=64,blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    aadhaar_number = models.IntegerField(unique=True,blank=False)
    published = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    phone_number = models.IntegerField(unique=True,blank=False)
    dob = models.DateField()
    lon = models.FloatField()
    lat = models.FloatField()
    subdistrict = models.ForeignKey(Subdistrict,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    district = models.ForeignKey(District,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    state = models.ForeignKey(State,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.first_name)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from apply_main.models import *

class ApplyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    dob = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(
        attrs={
            'placeholder': 'MM/DD/YYYY'
        }
    ))
    
    middle_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            'placeholder':'Optional'
        }
    ))

    class Meta:
        model = Apply
        fields = [
            'first_name',
            'middle_name',
            'last_name',
            'aadhaar_number',
            'phone_number',
            'dob',
            'state',
            'district',
            'subdistrict',            
        ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['district'].queryset = District.objects.none()
        self.fields['subdistrict'].queryset = Subdistrict.objects.none()
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from donate import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

app_name = "apply_main"

urlpatterns = [
    path('apply/',views.apply,name='apply'),
    path('ajax/load-districts/', views.load_districts, name='ajax_load_districts'),
    path('ajax/load-subdistricts/', views.load_subdistricts, name='ajax_load_subdistricts'),

]+static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

apply_form.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block head_block %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'index.css' %}">
{% endblock head_block %}

{% block body_block %}

  <h2>Person Form</h2>

  <form method="post" id="applyForm" data-districts-url="{% url 'apply_main:ajax_load_districts' %}" data-subdistricts-url="{% url 'apply_main:ajax_load_subdistricts' %}" novalidate>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
      {{ form.as_table }}
    </table>
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
  </form>
  <script>console.log("outside");</script>
  
  
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
    $("#id_state").change(function () {
      var url = $("#applyForm").attr("data-districts-url");  // get the url of the `load_cities` view
      var stateId = $(this).val();  // get the selected country ID from the HTML input
      console.log("inside");
      console.log(url);
      console.log(stateId);
      $.ajax({                       // initialize an AJAX request
        url: url,                    // set the url of the request (= localhost:8000/hr/ajax/load-cities/)
        data: {
          'state': stateId       // add the country id to the GET parameters
        },
        success: function (data) {   // `data` is the return of the `load_cities` view function
          $("#id_district").html(data);  // replace the contents of the city input with the data that came from the server
        }
      });

    });

    $("#id_district").change(function () {
      var url = $("#applyForm").attr("data-subdistricts-url");  // get the url of the `load_cities` view
      var districtId = $(this).val();  // get the selected country ID from the HTML input
      console.log("inside");
      console.log(url);
      console.log(districtId);
      $.ajax({                       // initialize an AJAX request
        url: url,                    // set the url of the request (= localhost:8000/hr/ajax/load-cities/)
        data: {
          'district': districtId       // add the country id to the GET parameters
        },
        success: function (data) {   // `data` is the return of the `load_cities` view function
          $("#id_subdistrict").html(data);  // replace the contents of the city input with the data that came from the server
        }
      });

    });
  </script>

{% endblock %}
```

dist_dropdown_list_options.html

```
<option value="">---------</option>
{% for district in districts %}
<option value="{{ district.id }}">{{ district.district_name }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

subdist_dropdown_list_options.html

```
<option value="">---------</option>
{% for subdistrict in subdistricts %}
<option value="{{ subdistrict.id }}">{{ subdistrict.subdistrict_name }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

Let me know if any other information is required.

GitHub link - https://github.com/deshiyan1010/electronics-donation

Comment: Have you added jquery in `base.html` also because it also happen when version mismatch

Comment: Yep. jQuery 3.5.1 slim min. But won't it be over written by the above specification?

Comment: try with putting this min.js to base html and remove from here

Comment: Thanks alot Pruthvi. It's working!!!

Comment: Thank you @PruthviBarot, where do you place the library script is super important. And sometimes is not very intuitive. But in my case your suggestion worked immediately!

Answer (score 0):

It's possible I'm missing something here, but the change listener you're binding to `'#id_state'`... where is this element? Is there additional markup you've omitted? Also, what happens when you attempt to trace the `$` object? The `$.ajax` object?

I've duplicated your code locally, and I'm having no trouble locating the ajax method in the jQuery library, though its native trapping fails to throw an error when it proves unable to target the `id_state` element.

A quick alteration to your script, changing...

`$("#id_state").change(function () {`

...to its vanilla JS equivalent...

`document.querySelector("#id_state").addEventListener('change', () => {`

...makes the field's omission clear.

When I manually supply a field that's been given the requisite ID `id_state`, however, it steps through to the ajax request (in both versions of the code), though I (unsurprisingly) get a 400 error when it attempts to connect to a URL unavailable on my local network.

Is there more data you could provide?

Comment: In your `meta` class within `ApplyForm`, you appear to have declared the fields as `'state'`,`'district'`, and `'subdistrict'`, though elsewhere you have references to `'state_name'`, and `'state_id'`. Were it me attempting to debug this, I'd do a quick sweep through and verify my variables, field names/id's, and then trace the object and the bindings, straight off the bat.

Comment: Please ignore that part. I have commented it out for a testing. I have removed that commented part to avoid confusion.

Comment: I will give the GitHub repo link.

Comment: Please do check the GitHub repo: https://github.com/deshiyan1010/electronics-donation

Comment: Thanks alot NerdyDeeds. Prithvi gave a solution and its working now.

Comment: Ah! Good catch, @Pruthvi Barot! Sorry I'm not getting back to you sooner, but it was 1am here when I left my comment. Glad you found the solution! :)